# WPF apps .Core 3.0 and microsoft ribbon control library 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.0, ribboncontrolslibrary

Hello I tried to build an application using the WPF,.Netcore 3.0 and microsoft  ribbon control library 4.0 and it's failed.

I need help or an example on the web.
I did look at [Microsoft WPF-Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples) on GitHub but did not find a ribbon sample working on .netcore 3.0

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDoNetcore3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDoNetcore3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">
            <ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <ribbon:RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
            </ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar >
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton1" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
                </ribbon:RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </ribbon:Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png">
                    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                      x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                      ImageSource="Images\Largeicon.png"/>
                </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                              Header="Home">
                <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                    Header="Group1">
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                         LargeImageSource="Images\Largeicon.png"
                                         Label="Button1" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button2"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button2" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button3"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button3" />
                    <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button4"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button4" />
                </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
            </ribbon:RibbonTab>
        </ribbon:Ribbon>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Mainwindow.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace WpfDoNetcore3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: [Github project](https://github.com/JeanMarcFlamand/WPF-Ribbon-dotnet-core-3.0-sample)

Comment: The package was updated at 2014, not sure, that it can support .NET core. You can run portability analyzer to check its compatibility, have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/migration/convert-project-from-net-framework)

Comment: Thanks. I did the portability analyzer on RibbonControlsLibrary.dll file   The summary result shows the following: 100.00 % for .NET Core + Platform Extensions,Version=v3.0, 23.25 % for .NET Core,Version=v3.0 and 23.38 % for .NET Standard + Platform Extensions,Version=v2.0. Not sure to understand the results but I think that  the Ribbon RibbonControlsLibrary.dll failed did not pass the test for .NET Core,Version=v3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `xmlns:ribbon` namespace declaration and the `ribbon:` prefix from your XAML and try to build:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDoNetcore3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">
            <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
            </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar >
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton1" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2" 
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png" />
                </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
            </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png">
                    <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                      x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                      ImageSource="Images\Largeicon.png"/>
                </RibbonApplicationMenu>
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                              Header="Home">
                <RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                    Header="Group1">
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                         LargeImageSource="Images\Largeicon.png"
                                         Label="Button1" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="Button2"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button2" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="Button3"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button3" />
                    <RibbonButton x:Name="Button4"
                                         SmallImageSource="Images\Smallicon.png"
                                         Label="Button4" />
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This should work. The `Ribbon` controls have been part of the WPF itself since .NET Framework 4.5, so you don't have to reference and use any external library if you target Framework 4.5+ or .NET Core 3+.

Comment: Now I can see the ribbon now in the visual designer now. Thanks. I did also correct all "image source", a "/" was missed in front of "Image" and "/" instead of "\" in the path.